# Why Merge Sort time complexity is not O(N)?

Tags: sorting

Merge Sort time complexity is  O(n log n) so here n is dominate on logn , so  Is Merge-Sort is O(N)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`O(n log n)`  is the best that you can get using tradional sort algorithms.

You can't say that  `O(n log n) == O(n)` even if  `n` dominates `logn` because they are multiplying not adding.

If you got `n + logn` and  `n` dominates `logn` then you can say that `O` is `O(n)`